# ROS2/create_subscription: How to pass callback arguments

Tags: ros, ros2, subscribe, callback

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In ROS 1, I was able to pass arguments to the callback function of a subscriber:
rospy.Subscriber(topic_name, type, call_back, **call_back_arg**)

How can I do this in ROS2?
My goal is to pass the name of the topic. Because I have a single call back for many topics and when the callback is invoked, I need to know what topic called it. It there a better way to find this?
Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/362954/ros2/create_subscription:--how-to-pass-callback-arguments/) by [afar](https://answers.ros.org/users/32894/afar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 111 on 2020-10-06

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [akashbhavsar](https://answers.ros.org/users/92260/akashbhavsar/) on 2021-12-27**:
Hey,I am also kind of stuck at same situation. can you post the answer if you have already.

**Comment by [afar](https://answers.ros.org/users/32894/afar/) on 2021-12-27**:
Please see the below answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

One of the ROS2 developers, "Ivan Santiago Paunovic", answered this question as following:

You can easily solve this using a lambda:

node.create_subscription(std_msgs.msg.String, "my_topic", lambda msg: common_callback(msg, other_args), 10)

[Reference in Github](https://github.com/ros2/rclpy/issues/629)

---

Originally posted by [afar](https://answers.ros.org/users/32894/afar/) with karma: 111 on 2021-12-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1